# How to load view controller without button in storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, viewcontroller

I want to load view controller without button. 
I set the identifier to 10 and tried to use

```
if(...){ 
    //load ViewController2
    [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"10"];
}
```

but nothing happens.

with this function it`s doesn`t work too

```
 UIViewController *vc = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"10"];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc];
```

here is my progect
http://www.sendspace.com/file/kfjhd5

whats a problem?

Comment: Use DrummerB's suggestion, or use `presentViewController`. Depends upon whether you're using navigation controller or not.

Comment: By the way, I notice you posted a [follow-up question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12499695/). I'd suggest you go ahead and flag DrummerB's answer below as correct and refer to that other question's answer for resolution of your underlying issue (which is unrelated to the `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` issue).

Answer (score 1):

Calling `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:` will instantiate a view controller, as it says. Nothing more. If you want to actually show it you have to use a variable and push it to your view controller stack.

```
UIViewController *vc = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"10"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc];
```

Of course you have to be using a [`UINavigationController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to do this.